# Min-height not working properly with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using the tailwind class `min-h-screen` but it's not changing the height of the element. It's not even displayed in the dev tools. When setting the height in the style property like `style="height: 100vh;"` it changes the height of the element.

```
<div class="bg-white flex-1 p-6 flex flex-col w-3/4 xl:w-full 
z-10 min-h-screen" style="box-shadow: 4px 0 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">
    content
</div>
```

The height ain't set anywhere else but there.

I came up editing the config file with `minHeight: {'m100v': '100vh'}` but the standard way should work, I guess.

Comment: did you declare some custom minHeight values in your tailwind.config.js ?

Comment: @MihaiT I just edited the question. I did just now and it works as it should. But the standard class doesn't.

Comment: No no, i meant except that one. Did you put some custom values for minHeight in the config ?

Comment: Ohh, I see! I forgot to put the custom settings into the "extend"  block so the default ones got overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you've put custom values for minHeight in your tailwind config. It doesn't matter if they are different than the default ones, the default ones will be ignored.

So, if you want to add custom values you need to extend your theme object . See below

```
module.exports = {

   theme: {
      extend: {
       minHeight: {
           'custom': '234',
           }
      },
   }
}
```

Then you leave the default values ones intact.